# Как подгрузить js файл в нужный момент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Нужно подгрузить(и выполнить) js - файл в нужный момент.

Пример есть обект который содержыт информацию о компоненте

```js
obj = [
  {
  "name": "shreck",
  "dataNam" : "52342",
  "linck" : "js/data/personaj.js" 
  },
  {
  "name" : "StajiGalactiki",
  "dataNam" : "3124656",
  "linck" : "js/data/film.js"
  }
]
```

в обекте есть ссылка на js код который отредерит данный конкретный обект.
Пример обект с названием "shreck" имеет ссылку на компонент "personaj" который отрендерит этот обект. Тоже самое из обектом "StajiGalactiki", который должен отрендерить компонет "film";

Можно ли сделать, чтоб при клике на таб c названием "shreck"  вытягивалась ссылка из обекта на компонент "personaj.js" который загрузиться и отрендерит данный компонент именно после клика по табу ?

Интересует загрузка и выполнение js файла именно по какомкто событию буть то таймер, или клик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, это сделать можно.

```
let element = document.createElement("script", { src: 'folder/script.js' });
let head = document.querySelector("head");
head.appendChild(element);
```

Если в скрипте есть еще и обработка события загрузки страницы, его можно инициировать так:

```
window.dispatchEvent(Event("load"));
```

Элемент, к которому применяется событие, да и само событие, могут быть другими, разумеется.